# Verify data from a HTML cell and display a message according to an interval

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

Basically I'm working on a HTML form that will validate some numbers (soil pollutants concentrations inserted manually) and give a message in a cell at the end, according to where on a scale those numbers are situated

In my case, the concentration of copper in the soil is *x=500 mg/kg*. 
I need to verify this number with some intervals limits for soil pollution *(400 < x < 1800= poluted)* and display a message like:

> "your soil is considered polluted"

because the concentration is over 400 mg/kg, for example.

Can someone give me an idea on how to do this? 
I need to integrate this into a webpage.

Comment: How is this related to JAVA? [JavaScript is not JAVA](http://kb.mozillazine.org/JavaScript_is_not_Java) - also show your form and whatever script you wrote

Comment: Not sure why you need java to integrate it with your webpage. If you want to do something in java on the client side then Applet may be the solution. However it looks javascript alone can solve the prob.

Comment: @pundit *"If you want to do something in java on the client side then Applet may be the solution."* If an applet is the solution, the app. designers are typically asking the wrong questions or seeking the wrong goals.  See [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/) for some of the reasons. *"However it looks javascript alone can solve the prob."*  OTOH +1 for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel submit
    let val = this.copper.value;
    const copper = isNaN(val) || val.trim() === "" ? 0 : +val; // convert to number
    let text = "Please enter a numeric value";
    if (copper > 0) {
      text = "Your soil is ";
      if (copper <= 400) text += "not polluted";
      else if (copper < 1800) text += "considered polluted";
      else text += "considered strongly polluted";
    }
    document.getElementById("soilMessage").innerHTML = text;
  })
})
```

```html
<title>Soil analysis</title>
<form id="form1">
  <input type="text" name="copper" id="copper" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value=" Validate " />
</form>
<div id="soilMessage"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you mplungjan, that will get me started ! I'm really a noob in this domain but it greatly simplifies my work to try to create my own tools. Your help is much appreciated !

Comment: one little question, what should i do if I want to add 3 different messages for  each interval, let's say, one message for under 400 and another for values above 1800 ?

Comment: Thank you for your help, that is what I was looking for @mplungjan , now to make that work for 37 more polluants :)

Comment: Hmm - it always pays to tell up front exactly what the issue is. Let me change my script

Comment: yes, you are right, I should have told that I'm trying in fact to validate 37 values, with 3 intervals for each value (under a limit, between an interval and over a limit) and according to where all the values are positioned it should give the message at the end

Comment: I am fiddling with this, but it is a bit too much like work :) http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/EMGYq/ - does not currently work, but perhaps you get the idea

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan, you did more than enough to point me in the right direction because this morning I had no idea from where to start. I'll post the result here if and when I'll have something working